# No power is generating

Tags: power, power-generation

I am trying to generate an small dc power using an old transformers and small magnets. For test, I stick a few mobile speaker's (Nokia 6300) magnets in dc motor and spin as much as possible near of transformer and connected the transformer's dc output terminals to the multimeter but even droplet of power is not generating. I also tried setting multimeter to an AC mode, it's not working yet. Please any helps ?

Comment: "the transformer's dc output" transformers don't have DC output, so something is fishy here

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. You state that you want to generate DC power. You want to use transformers and magnets. You place magnets in a DC motor. You spin the motor near a transformer. You mention the transformer's DC output. First of all transformers do not have a DC output. Secondly, I am guessing here that you mean that you used a DC motor to spin magnets near a transformer, magnetic feald applied externally to a transformer will not induce significant voltage in the transformer because the core surrounds the windings and most of the flux will not pass through the winding.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I mean the output terminals of transformer by dc output of transformer.

Comment: It basically comes down to the fact that you don't understand what you're doing which is preventing you from understanding why this will never work. If you want to learn, great, get a book about electricity etc. and read it. Just trying things you do not understand will bring you nothing.

Comment: Do you have an actual transformer, or do you have a 'wall wart' (google it) which you're calling a transformer, but is actually a AC-DC switching power supply ... ?

Comment: Also, if you're running the output of spinning a dc motor to generate electricity, then you're creating a dc short-circuit in one xfmr winding. In order to use the teansformer, you need to feed it AC power, dc just shorts one set of windings with no real power transfer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to split the transformer like this to get any significant induced voltage: -

[image]

The magnets should be spinning close to the centre core limb and now the flux is forced to pass through the iron of that limb. When you had this setup: -

[image]

The "I" part of the core is preventing any significant amount of flux passing into the central limb of the transformer where the winding is.

In fact any closed-form core and any type of winding will suffer the same problem - the change in field brought about by the magnets rotating need to "impact" on the air gap at the end of the coil.